# BeginScope in .Net Framework 4.5

Tags: logging, .net-4.5, serilog

I´ve worked with .NET Core recently and had pretty good experience with Serilog. Now I´m on a project which targets .NET Framework 4.5 and I´m looking for a way to use the `BeginScope()`-Functionality. This Method is part of Microsoft.Extensions.Logging -Namespace which can only be used with .NET Standard 2.0, which is not compatible with .NET Framework 4.5.

Any ideas to solve either the dependency-problem or to write this Method as an Extension for Serilog?

Thanks in advance